# Gradle: define variables within a scope?

Tags: variables, dictionary, gradle, groovy, scope

In Gradle, can we define and access variables like the following? a more convenient way to define variables within a scope (namespace).

```
foo {
   bar1 {
      variable1 = 'hello';
      variable2 = 'hello2';
   }

   bar2 {
      variable1 = 'hello';
      variable2 = 'hello2';
   }

}

println foo.bar1.variable1
println foo.bar2.variable2
```

Or a map is required

```
foo = [bar1 : [variable1 : 'hello', 
               variable2 : 'hello2'
              ],
       bar2 : [variable1 : 'hello', 
               variable2 : 'hello2'
              ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [ConfigSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html)

Set your variables in `foo.groovy`

```
foo {
    bar1 {
        variable1 = 'hello'
        variable2 = 'hello2'
    }
    bar2 {
        variable1 = 'hello'
        variable2 = 'hello2'
    }
}
```

And then load it

```
ConfigSlurper foo = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('/path/to/foo.groovy').toURI().toURL())

println foo.bar1.variable1
println foo.bar2.variable2
```

Comment: Defined in a properties file will not support groovy object, only string.

Comment: @eastwater that's not true. The file that is read by ConfigSlurper is a Groovy script. You can use Groovy syntax, calculate stuff, refer one variable from the other, .... The naming `.properties` in the example is simply wrong.

Comment: Indeed, `foo.groovy` would be better

Comment: @ToYonos, justed edited based on the comment. Hope this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually see it done is with an `ext` block in a separate script

ie, in `gradle/common.gradle`:

```
ext {
    foo = [
        bar1: [
            variable1 : 'hello',
            variable2 : 'hello2'
        ],
        bar2: [
            variable1 : 'hello',
            variable2 : 'hello2'
        ]
    ]
}
```

Then in your build script;

```
applyScript 'common.gradle'
```

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to achieve `local` & `global` scoping in `gradle` `tasks`, We can do something like this,

```
def version = "3.0"

task Task1 {
    description "sample task #1"
    doLast {
        version = "1.0"
        println "exec doLast - task 1"
        println "since verison - $version"
    }
}

task Task2 {
    description "sample task #2"
    doLast {
        version = "1.0"
        println "exec doLast - task 2"
        println "since verison - $version"
    }
}

task Task3 {
    description "sample task #3"
    dependsOn Task1
    doLast {
        version = "2.0"
        println "exec doLast - task 3"
        println "since verison - $version"
    }
}

task Task4 {
    description "sample task #4"
    dependsOn Task3, Task2
    doLast {
        println "exec doLast - task 4"
        println "since verison - $version"
    }
}
```

This creates a global variable `version` and then every task creates a local variable `version` as per the usage.

**working**: 
Since local variables are defined inside `doLast`, they are created at the time of running `task` and not during `configuration` step of gradle build lifecycle.